# Ruby cucumber: How to ignore IE protected mode error in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

My test automation is experiencing error using IE browser.

```
  Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings 
  are not the same for all zones. 
  Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value 
  (enabled or disabled) for all zones. 
  (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError)
```

In order to let the test run, I have to manually unchecked them all in IE options. I did some research, there is a way to ignore it in java, but I have not found it in Ruby. What I found is below (I am not using remote server):

```
  IE

   Make sure that Internet Options → Security has the same 
   Protected Mode setting (on or off, it doesn't 
   matter as long as it is the same value) for all zones.

   From: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings
```

My env:

```
  Ruby: 1.9.3
  Selenium WebDriver: 2.53
  Cucumber: 2.1
```

Anyone has done this pragmatically in Ruby? Please share your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The desired capabilities include a flag that disables this protected mode check. Note that while disabling the check will allow you to open IE, you may or may not get issues later on. Here is what the [Selenium Wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#ie-specific) says about the flag:

> Whether to skip the protected mode check. If set, tests may become
>   flaky, unresponsive, or browsers may hang. If not set, and protected
>   mode settings are not the same for all zones, an exception will be
>   thrown on driver construction. Only "best effort" support is provided
>   when using this capability.

Assuming that correctly setting the IE Protected Mode settings is not an option, here is how you disable the check in Selenium-WebDriver:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internet_explorer(
  'ignoreProtectedModeSettings' => true
)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:internet_explorer, :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

If you are curious about the history of the IEDriver and Protected Mode, Jim Evans has an interesting blog post, "[You're Doing It Wrong: IE Protected Mode and WebDriver](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.ca/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) ."

Comment: Thank you Justin! You have good points. I will discuss with our testers on the options. Thanks again!